# In maven how can I include non-java src files in the same place in the output jar?

Tags: jar, maven

I received a source code bundle. Inside the src directory tree there are some properties files(.properties) which I want to keep in the output jar in the same place. e.g: I want

```
src/main/java/com.mycompany/utils/Myclass.java 
src/main/java/com.mycompany/utils/Myclass.properties
```

to stay the same in the jar:

```
com.mycompany/utils/Myclass.class 
com.mycompany/utils/Myclass.properties
```

without needing to add the properties file it to separate resources folder. Is there a way to I tell this to maven?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could add the following in your pom indicating that the resources are available in `src/main/java` and `including` the type of resources.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: If you put them in **src/main/resources** they are included by default.

Comment: FYI, for those new to maven, the resources node goes under the <build> node if it is not already present.

Comment: ...and if you put them in src/main/resources, then you may have to setup a folder structure like src/main/resources/com/mycompany/utils

Answer (score 14):

With this pom fragment you include anything that is not a java file for both main and test artifact:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Comment: If you only want to include one special file from that directory, then add the line `<includes><include>**/special.file</include></includes>`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for : `<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>`

Answer (score 2):

Include and mix all your non .java src files and the src/main/resources:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```