# Maven clean install vs install

Tags: maven

When I run the maven install everything works fine. All the classes get compiled and my build is also successful. 
But when I run maven clean install one of the java test classes could not find the xml that is referenced in @ContextConfiguration.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: There's probably some other thing putting the XML file where it's expected. Where are you putting the XML file? Is it in `src/main/resources` or `test/main/resources` where it belongs?

Comment: I dont have that file in both of those. I have it in some other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You IDE is "helping" you put resources into the classpath.

When running maven clean the entire target/ directory is removed, so if things exist otherwise, it is because someone else copies into it.

Resources in maven usually goes in src/main/resources or src/test/resources unless otherwise configured. Your xml file is probably in a src/main/java or src/test/java folder, and therefore being copied by the IDE.

If you want to have resources inside your java folders, a helpful answer is this one:

[In maven how can I include non-java src files in the same place in the output jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509309/in-maven-how-can-i-include-non-java-src-files-in-the-same-place-in-the-output-ja)

Comment: Thank you. It resolved my issue. Included the required xml file through resources include in pom.xml